# dynamic list sorting without using sort array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was thinking of some sort algorithm to perform dynamic array sorting list,  but this http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/1/ seem able to solve my problem with cleaner code. But there's still few steps left to be done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var lvl = $('select').val();
    var ref = $('li.level' + lvl).last();
    $('<li class="level" '+ lvl + '>' + lvl + ' </li>').insertAfter(ref);
  });
});
```

what if initially I don't have any HTML markup, what is in my head now is use 3 if statement to check whether it's the 1st li when the user insert a li. is there any other better ways?

Comment: `$('ul').children('li').length` if it's greater than 0 a `li` is already present, at least I think. If it's correct you could also set a Boolean to avoid to check the Dom each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/14/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var lvl = $('select').val();
    var ref = $('li.level' + lvl).last();
    var newLi =  $('<li class="level'+ lvl + '">' + lvl + ' </li>');

    (ref.length > 0) ? newLi.insertAfter(ref) : $("ul").append(newLi);
  });
});
```

Or like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/20/)

```
(ref.length > 0) ? ref.after(newLi) : $("ul").append(newLi);
```

Comment: will this be hard to be load from db or save to db? I've to retrieve everything include its position from db, what is the challenge? or just insert them 1 by 1 like normal and then sort them using sql query?

Comment: how do you want to show it. do you want to show level 1, 2 and 3in order?

Comment: are you going to give separate label for each li? store it like this. If you are going to give label for each li structre like this. `{1: [label, label], 2: [label, label], 3: [label, label]}`. 1, 2, 3 are representing levels.

Comment: I found it got a problem, what I want is not just they grouped together, I try the code with level 3 appended 1st, later i choose level 1, the level 1 is on the top of level 3..